# How to install mlflow using pip install

Tags: pip, mlflow

I'm working on a Window 10 machine and trying to pip install mlflow but I'm getting the following error message.

```
THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
mlflow from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/01/ec/8c9448968d4662e8354b9c3a62e635f8929ed507a45af3d9fdb84be51270/mlflow-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=0f2f116a377b9da538642eaf688caa0a7166ee1ede30c8734830eb9e789574b4:
    Expected sha256 0f2f116a377b9da538642eaf688caa0a7166ee1ede30c8734830eb9e789574b4
         Got        eb34ea16ecfe02d474ce50fd1f88aba82d56dcce9e8fdd30193ab39edf32ac9e
```

Comment: Added a tag because the issue is with pip not mlflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is trying to check cache for packages. They were likely compiled in linux or some other OS and you are trying to install them in Windows.

This should fix your issue:

```
pip install --no-cache-dir mlflow
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my original post, I'm getting a different error now.

Comment: If this answered your original question you should mark it as an accepted answer and ask a new question. It is not good practice to add onto a question as it may mislead future visitors of the site.